# Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on... flutter_test from sdk is forbidden, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm having this issue when I've added http dependency in my flutter project. Can anyone please help me with it?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this article](https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 57):

If you get the message:

> Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on...

It means flutter_test depends on a dependency with version lower than you specified in another dependency.

To solve this, open pubspec.yaml, and remove the version number of the problem dependency:

Example:

Change

```
  archive: ^2.0.13 --> remove this number
```

To:

```
  archive:
```

Comment: How to upgrade the flutter_test?

Comment: use flutter upgrade

Comment: Is this recommended solution? As far as I know omitting dependency version is discouraged

Comment: this solution works, but is it possible to degreade the versions for the dependency needed by fluttr_test?

Answer (score 17):

You have provided or trying to use `http: ^0.12.0` dependency on implementing API calls in **pubspec.yaml** file but **flutter_test** will require `http: ^0.11.3+17`. That's why it fails. Please replace

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0
```

with

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.11.3
```

Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered this error when trying to update the [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package.

My error:

```
Because butler_labs depends on flutter from sdk which depends on collection 1.17.1, collection 1.17.1 is required.
So, because butler_labs depends on collection ^1.17.2, version solving failed.
```

The solution was to run `flutter update-packages --force-upgrade` which updated the dependencies in my local instance of Flutter. This command is mentioned in the [official docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#updating-package-dependencies).

Answer (score 6):

I was facing a similar error. I solved it by removing all the version numbers from the `dependencies:` section in `pubspec.yaml`.

So, if my `pubspec.yaml` looked like this before:

```
dependencies:
  freezed_annotation: ^0.14.3
```

I changed it to this:

```
dependencies:
  freezed_annotation:
```

I'm **assuming** this fetches the latest "possible" version of each package.

Comment: This answer is the same as (or very similar to) [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394530/8517948). It would be better to upvote that answer instead of posting it again. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers that helped you.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I somehow deleted `sdk: flutter`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: What does `sdk: flutter` mean?

Answer (score 2):

In my case IDE referred to an an older version of dart because of fvm. Seems like 'run' button called `fvm flutter run`, but not `flutter run` as I expected. After I deleted fvm folder from the project the problem has gone.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the dependency version that you were added in your pubspec.yaml file
don't use the current or latest version try some previous versions of dependency.

for ex - if you are using latest sqflite version then chnage to previous version of that and then re-run your whole project.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32077882)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide the dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml`? It looks like your app depends on at least `http 0.12.0` but flutter_test specifically requires `http 0.11.3+17` (an older version) which makes it fail.

Comment: I wanted to have the latest version of http dependency but it looks like flutter current beta version doesn't support it so I removed the version constraint and it stopped giving me the error and added the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If your app doesn't have too many dependencies that could broke, you can try to upgrade your Flutter version: `flutter upgrade`.
It most probably will fix this problem. But always be sure to understand that your app might break at unexpected places.
So you're fine if:

- either you're doing it for small app
- or it's big app at work and it has extensive tests that will tell you something has broken
- if big app without tests, be sure to test every important place of the app, where dependencies are being used

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the matcher package has encountered the following issue, which is the real case I suffered in the past:

```
Because matcher >=0.12.15 depends on test_api ^0.5.0 and every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.16, matcher >=0.12.15 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk.
So, because myapp depends on both flutter_test from sdk and matcher ^0.12.15, version solving failed.
```

Simply run three commands subsequently:

```bash
flutter pub remove matcher
flutter pub add --dev matcher

flutter pub get
```

Finally there is a line change in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
# before
  matcher: ^0.12.15

# after
  matcher: ^0.12.13
```

And `myapp` can be run successfully using the above solution to upgrade flutter in channel stable, and upgrade flutter pub packages:

```bash
# upgrade flutter in channel stable
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade

# upgrade flutter pub packages
flutter pub outdated
flutter pub upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Because flutter_cab depends on flutter_google_places_hoc081098 ^1.2.0 which depends on http ^0.13.4, http ^0.13.4 is required.
So, because flutter_cab depends on http ^1.2.0, version solving failed.
I am facing this issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change depending attributes version inside pubspec.yaml
if it says depands on http *** than change http version
or if it says depands on collection *** than change collection version.

Answer (score 0):

run `flutter upgrade`. This problem occurs because your library is using the SDK version.